# Pricing 0% interest rate Floor Black Model

Tags: black-scholes, interest-rates, derivatives

I'm having some trouble pricing a 0% interest rate Floor following Black's formula. The term d1 contains the expresion Ln(Forward/Strike) 
if the strike is exactly 0 this expresion yields an indetermination and therefore we can't compute N(d1) in the pricing formula.

I was wondering how to work around this. A peer suggested to compute the regular formula using a 100% probability, but the results are not really meningful.

Aside from the displaced model is there any other adjustment to the black model to price a 0% interest rate floor?

Comment: Usually for Floors, strike is given in absolute terms with reference to the at-the-money (ATM) level. In your case, the strike would therefore be Forward + 0% i.e. your floor is ATM and Ln(Forward/Strike) = 0.

Comment: Hi, in my case I only have 0% interest as a given Floor. From what you said I understand that we have 100% probability to execute the Floor which will translate in a N(d2) = 1 and then plug the 1 in BS formula. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Forget about this 100% probability, just plug in Black's formula the relevant parameters (i.e. Forward, Strike, Implied volatility and time-to-maturity) and compute the floor price.

Comment: Still not sure about how to just "plug" the Strike since this is 0% d1 is simply undetermined

Comment: No, the strike is equal to the forward price as you have an absolute strike of 0%

Comment: In this case the Strike is an actual 0% in order to prevent rates to fall into negative territory. Has nothing to do with being a relative to the forward floor. That brings me back to the indetermination issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the forward is $> 0$ then under the Black & Scholes model the probability of underlying rate being $\leq 0$ is zero, so that the $0\%$ strike floor is worth zero. If the forward is $\leq 0$ (as has been happening since rates went into the negative territory) then the Black & Scholes model is meaningless since it models the underlying as being log normal. 
This is why practitioners have resorted to the displaced log normal model, where the variable $underlying + displacement$ is assumed to be log normal, with $displacement$ an additional parameter of the model.

Answer (score 0):

in interest rates , the logN model is not correct since rates can be negative.
so you should use the Normal (Gaussian) model, this is the standard now.